# Display different maps with onClick event - Google Maps V3.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to display 4 different maps based on a click event. While I do have this particular interaction happening, the map itself isn't being centered properly and also fails to actually load the map in the center [SCREENSHOT HERE](http://cl.ly/TAQy).

The way I've managed to do this currently is a bit of a hack as I'm not the greatest with JS and fairly new with Google Maps integration, so pardon if the code is crap. Feel free to offer better, more elegant solutions.

Thus far I've done this: 
- Created and initialized four different maps. 
- Plotted the associated marker with the associate map (dining map gets restaurant locations, etc). 
- When clicking related nav element, the map should display (click dining, dining map displays)

This works, but the map isn't displaying properly. [LIVE DEMO](http://pbj.me/dev/enk/gmap/).

HTML:

```
<section class="recommend-map">
      <div class="col-one">
        <h1>Recommends Map</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="map-canvas">Map 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="map-canvas-2">Map 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="map-canvas-3">Map 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="map-canvas-4">Map 4</a></li>
          </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-two">
        <div class="content1" id="map-canvas" style="width: 550px; height: 300px;" data-location="javitz">
        </div>
        <div class="content2" id="map-canvas-2" style="width: 550px; height: 300px;" data-location="javitz">
        </div>  
        <div class="content3" id="map-canvas-3" style="width: 550px; height: 300px;" data-location="pier92">
        </div>
        <div class="content4" id="map-canvas-4" style="width: 550px; height: 300px;" data-location="pier94">
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

JS:

```
function initialize() {
// removed actual array data for brevity, it was a lot. 

var dining = [
      ["Yankee Stadium",  40.829584,-73.927571],
      ["South Street Seaport", 40.70514,-74.008734],
      ["Musical", 40.762341,-73.978329],
      ["Frick collection!", 40.771385,-73.967171]
      ];

var drinks = [
     ["Central Park ", 40.78678,-73.966312],
     ["Broadway Shows",  40.765461,-73.984337],
     ["Broadway musicals", 40.762471,-73.970947],
     ["Musical", 40.736169,-74.001621]
     ];

var roofOutdoor = [
      ["The Ballet",  40.73495,-73.998671],
      ["Central Park",  40.78678,-73.966312],
      ["Broadway shows",  40.756685,-73.987813],
      ["Galapagos artspaace",   40.703871,-73.990924]
      ];

var leisure = [
        ["Chelsea Girl",  40.725169,-74.003005],
        ["What Goes Around Comes Around", 40.722925,-74.00323],
        ["The Library", 40.752166,-73.981708]
      ];

      var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(40.75688,-73.984264);

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: mapCenter,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-2'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: mapCenter,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var map3 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-3'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: mapCenter,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var map4 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas-4'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: mapCenter,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        var marker, marker2, marker3, marker4, i;



        // Map1 Markers
        for (i = 0; i < dining.length; i++) {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(dining[i][4], dining[i][5]),
            map: map
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent("<h1>" + dining[i][0] + "</h1><p>" + dining[i][1] + "</p><p>" + dining[i][2] + "</p><p>" + dining[i][3] + "</p>");
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            }
          })(marker, i));
        }

        // Map2 Markers
        for (i = 0; i < drinks.length; i++) {
          marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(drinks[i][1], drinks[i][2]),
            map: map2
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, 'click', (function(marker2, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(drinks[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map2, marker2);
            }
          })(marker2, i));
        }

        // Map3 Markers
        for (i = 0; i < roofOutdoor.length; i++) {
          marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(roofOutdoor[i][1], roofOutdoor[i][2]),
            map: map3
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', (function(marker3, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(roofOutdoor[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map3, marker3);
            }
          })(marker3, i));
        }

        // Map4 Markers
        for (i = 0; i < leisure.length; i++) {
          marker4 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(leisure[i][1], leisure[i][2]),
            map: map4
          });

          google.maps.event.addListener(marker4, 'click', (function(marker4, i) {
            return function() {
              infowindow.setContent(leisure[i][0]);
              infowindow.open(map4, marker4);
            }
          })(marker4, i));
        }
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

});
```

Comment: Why not use 1 map and display only the markers you want?

Comment: @putvande That could work as well. But I guess I'd have to toggle the links to remove/display the proper markers. Not sure how I'd begin to implement that though. 

I guess I could just bind the hide/display to a particular button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before.

I used jquery for my client side JS.

**HTML**
first, I would try rendering all the maps at the same time. yes. simple make them all visible so that they each push each-other around.

**CSS**
second, you have "position:absolute;" try "position:inline-block;"

**JS**
finally,

call "$("SELECTOR NAME").hide();" on the 3 maps you want hidden initially at the top of the JS code.

then "$("SELECTOR NAME").toggle();" to turn on or off the other ones.

reason: I believe what's happening now is you have the 3 initially hidden maps **generated**, such that the DOM doesn't actually have the generated content when the client loads the page. Generated DOM objects need **delegated** manipulation. The first map works fine because its generated **with the DOM**.

I could give you a actual code example tonight, I'm at work atm sorry.

Comment: There is no such thing as `position: inline-block`. I think you mean `display: inline-block`?

Comment: oops yes! position:relative; display:inline-block; or just block

Comment: I'll play around with this now. Let you know how it goes. Although, I wouldn't mind seeing a code sample when you get home from work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could just simple have 1 google map and unset and set markers on it.
Use `marker.setMap(null)` to unset markers from the map.
You have to keep track of these markers in an Array.

Something like this:

```
var markers = []; // To keep all markers
// array can be your array of 'dining', 'drinks', 'roofOutdoor' or 'leisure' which you could set by clicking on your a tag.

function setMarkers (array) {
    $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        // unset marker (they will be removed from the map)
        marker.setMap(null);
    });

    if (array !== undefined) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        $.each(array, function (index, value) {
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(value[1], value[1]);
            bounds.extend(pos);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map
            });
            markers.push(marker);

        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
}
```

I have added the `bounds` just to go to the markers so you are sure they are added to the map.

HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="setMarker(dining);">Show dining markers</a>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Super helpful. Great way of executing the map/markers too. I'll implement and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Just curious how I'd integrate this into the overall JS for a Google map?

Does it set inside the for loop that initiates the cycle over each array index? Or is this a separate function? Playing around with it now but not sure.

Just tried with it in both the for loop and outside of the entire initialize function, the error i'm getting is upon click. setMakers() is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted to implement it the same way here is a solution.

here's your button for the second map

```
<button id="map2">map2</button>
```

some inline js to hide maps 2 3 4 and leave 1 rendered

```
$('#2,#3,#4').hide();
```

this will show something between a div with the id="2" and hide everything else in the parent element

```
$("#map2").click(function() {
    $('#2').show().siblings().hide();
});
```

here's your map container

```
<div class="map" id="2"> your map here </div>
```

so if you want to keep things mostly the way you're doing it, this is the most simple. albeit inefficient and it might cause Google to stop resolving your API requests if you go over the limit. (they do limit the amount of requests they serve per day)

putvade's solution is much more elegant. You should use his solution surely :P

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution thanks to @MatUtter.

It's honestly a really bad hack. And normally they don't sit well with me. But for the time being I need something that 'works' since I'm in the process of a site-wide refactor (yay for corporate companies).

Basically, what I've realized (thanks to @MatUtter) is that when running $("SELECTOR").hide(); it is removing an element from the DOM. As it's supposed to, but then Google Maps is having a hard time redrawing the map, as it was originally there, then removed, then redrawn. At least thats my understanding of it.

So for now, I'm selecting each map element, hiding them with 'visibility:hidden' as that'll allow each map to maintain their position in the DOM but remove them from view. And upon clicking each associated link, it displays the appropriate map.

It's surely a hack, but it'll do for now. Thanks for the help folks!

[The most recent version of the site is here](http://pbj.me/dev/enk/gmap/), if you have any additional pieces of feedback or refactors you think are better let me know. I'm always open to revisions, and this my year for JS so I'm happy to learn :)