# How to include js files in header of wordpress pages that are activated on-click

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am attempting to use wordpress to build a website that integrates google maps. I am doing some overlays with the maps and use the google developers API and Python to make the appropriate javascript. I have successfully written the js files and Python necessary to accomplish this.

My website is built in Worpress and I would like add a page (not the home page) that has *n* links and each one would populate a box with the corresponding map. I can take care of the layout and design issues but I am at a loss on how to:

a) Include the javascript as a file that

b) gets called upon clicking the link and thus populates that map without calling a new page

That is, the javascript is HUGE because it may include thousands of lat/lon points. Therefore including *n* of these written into the header is unreasonable. I want to simply call it from *filename.js* when the link is clicked.

There is a plugin that allows me to include whatever I want in the header. So, if I can find out where to put the *.js files (or txt file) in the directory tree and how to have the corresponding file activated upon click I should be good. Thanks!

This [Display different maps with onClick event - Google Maps V3.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887110/display-different-maps-with-onclick-event-google-maps-v3) kind of helps with doing an on-click display but everyone's solution was to make one map. I cannot do that. I am overlaying vast amounts of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way you can get that done. (Jump down to the get started part of the script.)

For brevity, I've included a bunch of scripts in one 'file', but you'll want to break them in to individual files.

You may also need to try the html and js in jsbin [js bin example](https://output.jsbin.com/vabeqeh%20jsbin), b/c SO may or may not allow the dynamic loading of js.

```js
(function(undefined) {
  /**
   * @author (@colecmc)
   * @method turn collection into an array
   * @param {object} collection - NodeList, HTMLCollection, etc. Should have an "item" method and/or a "length" property
   */
  ToArray = collection => Array.prototype.slice.call(collection);

  /** \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ **/


  Observer = (function(undefined) {
    /**
     * pub sub
     */
    'use strict';

    var subUid = -1;
    return {
      topics: {},

      subscribe: function(topic, func) {
        /**
         * @param {string} topic
         * @param {function} func
         * @returns {string} - a token such as '3'
         * @example Observer.subscribe('any-valid-string',function(name,resp){
                console.log(resp.prop);
            });
         */
        if (!Observer.topics[topic]) {
          Observer.topics[topic] = [];
        }

        var token = (++subUid).toString();
        Observer.topics[topic].push({
          token: token,
          func: func
        });

        return token;
      },

      publish: function publish(topic, args) {
        /**
         * @param {string} topic
         * @param {object} args
         * @returns {boolean} - true if topic is valid, false otherwise
         * @example Observer.publish('any-valid-string',{
                prop: 'this is a test'
            });
         */
        if (!Observer.topics[topic]) {
          return false;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
          var subscribers = Observer.topics[topic],
            len = subscribers ? subscribers.length : 0;

          while (len--) {
            subscribers[len].func(topic, args);
          }
        }, 0);

        return true;
      },

      unsubscribe: function unsubscribe(token) {
        /**
         * @param {string} token - value should be saved from the original subscription
         * @example Observer.unsubscribe('2');
         * @example Observer.unsubscribe(member); - where member is the value returned by Observer.subscribe();
         */
        var m,
          forEachTopic = function(i) {
            if (Observer.topics[m][i].token === token) {
              Observer.topics[m].splice(i, 1);
              return token;
            }
          };

        for (m in Observer.topics) {
          if (Observer.topics.hasOwnProperty(m)) {
            Observer.topics[m].forEach(forEachTopic);
          }
        }

        return false;
      }
    };
  }(undefined));
  /** \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ **/

  SetAttributes = function(el, attrs) {
    /**
     * @author (@colecmc)
     * @method simple for in loop to help with creating elements programmatically
     * @param {object} el - HTMLElement attributes are getting added to
     * @param {object} attrs - object literal with key/values for desired attributes
     * @example SetAttributes(info,{
     *    'id' : 'utswFormInfo'
     *    'class' : 'my-class-name'
     * });
     */

    'use strict';
    var key;

    for (key in attrs) {
      if (attrs.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
      }
    }

    return el;
  };

  /** \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ **/


  GetScript = function(url, fullPath) {
    /**
     * @author (@colecmc)
     * @version 1.0.4
     * @requires Swlxws.SetAttributes, Swlxws.Observer
     * @method dynamically add script tags to the page.
     * @param {string} url - relative path and file name - do not include extension
     * @param {string} fullPath - absolute path
     * @example GetScript('myLocalScript');
     * @example GetScript('','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js');
     */

    'use strict';

    function onLoad(event) {
      var result;

      if (event.type === 'load') {
        result = 1;
      } else {
        result = -1;
      }

      Observer.publish('get-script-onload-complete', {
        successful: result,
        eventData: event
      });
    }

    var JSPATH = '/js/',
      /* or where ever you keep js files */
      el = document.createElement('script'),
      attrs = {
        defer: true,
        src: null,
        type: 'text/javascript'
      };

    /** look for a string based, protocol agnostic, js file url */
    if (typeof fullPath === 'string' && fullPath.indexOf('http') === 0) {
      attrs.src = fullPath;
    }

    /** look for any string with at least 1 character and prefix our root js dir, then append extension */
    if (typeof url === 'string' && url.length >= 1) {
      attrs.src = JSPATH + url + '.js';
    }

    SetAttributes(el, attrs);

    el.addEventListener('load', onLoad);
    el.addEventListener('error', onLoad);

    document.body.appendChild(el);

    return el;
  };

  /** \/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/ **/

  /**
   * Get Started
   */
  function onClick(event) {
    GetScript('', event.target.dataset.namespaceUrl);
  }

  Observer.subscribe('get-script-onload-complete', function(name, resp) {
    /** check to make resp is what you expect, ie: the correct script loaded */
    /** then it is safe to use */
  });

  ToArray(document.querySelectorAll('.load-scripts')).map(script => script.addEventListener('click', onClick, false));

}(undefined));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>How to include js files in header of wordpress pages that are activated on-click</title>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="#load" class="load-scripts" data-namespace-url="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js">Load Google Analytics</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `wp_enqueue_script()` to load the necessary JS files on only the templates you want.

As for your large data set, I recommend that you cache it in an external .json file and use `wp_enqueue_script()` to load it only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the onclick event suggestion is pretty much what you want and you are just concerned about the large amount of data. Then there are a few ways to tackle it. I am not sure if the dataset is a js file or php/json files but i came across a similar issue on one of my projects, dont remember properly but i was doing something with maxmind's ip/location data set.

So i just splitted the large file into 3 smaller ones. Then i looped through each of the file and if the stuff that i was looking for was found in the file then i just breaked out. And definitely as Brian suggested caching and using a CDN would help a lot.